# displays setting dialog is buggy

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, display

I'm sorry for the poor title, I hope I'll make myself clear here.

I have a Lenovo laptop (thinkpad 13 gen2) and a docking station. I connected to the docking station two monitors one via HDMI, and the other via VGA. Now when I try to arrange the monitors it behaves awkwardly:

1. Often, I cannot grab the monitor. The mouse cursor does change to the hand symbol, but it wont grab it.
2. When I manage to grab the monitor, it gets stuck on the corners of the other monitor (top right corner of one to bottom left of the other for example).
3. Many times, the apply button disappear.

Am I the only one experiencing this?